# How to read data from a file and set to different variable?

Tags: python, list

I have a file (integral.txt) that contains data as below.

```
    1 H    1   1
   3
    3.4252509100    0.2769343610
    0.6239137300    0.2678388518
    0.1688554000    0.0834736696
    2 H    1   2
   3
    4.4252509100    0.2769343610
    1.6239137300    0.2678388518
    0.1688554000    0.0834736696
```

I am doing a code that can read specific lines. For example, I want to read the first line as nbasis, label, natom, _ and then the program read the second line as input as I will use this number in for loop, and it can be different each time and depend on this number, I will read the next lines so if it was three, the program read three line and set to a variable called zeta1, cijk1 and do the same procedure with the next five lines.
I did the code as below, but my code read all the data as one variable.

```
nb = 2 ! This number can be different and here is the simplest case as the data file can be more lines so depend on this number I can read more 
with open("integral.txt","r") as input3:
     for b in range(nb):
         intr = input3.readline()
         nprimitive = int(input3.readline())
         nbasis, label, natom, _ = intr.split()
         for prim in range(nprimitive):
             intr2 = input3.readline()
             zeta , cijk = intr2.split()
             print(zeta,cijk)

Output
3.4252509100  0.2769343610
0.6239137300  0.2678388518
0.1688554000  0.0834736696
4.4252509100  0.2769343610
1.6239137300  0.2678388518
0.1688554000  0.0834736696

The output I want to get
    zeta1           cijk1
    3.4252509100    0.2769343610
    0.6239137300    0.2678388518
    0.1688554000    0.0834736696
    zeta2           cijk2
    4.4252509100    0.2769343610
    1.6239137300    0.2678388518
    0.1688554000    0.0834736696
```

Comment: Even if you could set variables from the input data, your code would have to depend on those variable names (which you can't predict, as they come from any input you might get). That's not really practical.
You may get a dictionary (say, {"zeta1" :  [3.4252509100, 0.6239137300, 0.1688554000], ...} or you could just print the values you got (under their headers). Does it make sense?

Comment: The problem that I will use them again, and I will do some calculation with zeta1 and zeta2 like multiply, so I need to have zeta1 has three values and zeta2 has other three values

Comment: The only thing I see different is that your output doesn't have a `print('zeta\tcijk')` with numbering

Comment: @StevenSummers but I want to separate each zeta as I will use each zeta and in my output. I have only one zeta. I want to get zeta depend on "nb" so if nb was 2. I will get zeta1 and zeta2. If it was 3 I can get zeta1, zeta2 and zeta3 and so on

Comment: From what you have doesn't it already do that? With `nb=2` you get the first 2 sets

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you only need to read the first number before the H.

You can use a regex for that:

```
import re

with open("integral.txt","r") as f:
    out = re.sub(r'[ \t]+(\d+) \w+[^\n]*\n\s+\d+[^\n]*', 
                 r'    zeta\1           cijk\1', f.read())
    print(out)
```

output:

```
    zeta1           cijk1
    3.4252509100    0.2769343610
    0.6239137300    0.2678388518
    0.1688554000    0.0834736696
    zeta2           cijk2
    4.4252509100    0.2769343610
    1.6239137300    0.2678388518
    0.1688554000    0.0834736696
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but It is not what I want

Comment: @Zema can you explain why? ideally also provide a counter-example

Comment: The data is inside a file, and you used the data direct, but I need to read the data from the file. According to your method, Can I multiply zeta1 with zeta2 ?

Comment: I see, I just skept this part as I thought it is obvious. Of course you can do the same from a file. What is the output that you went? Print or a new file?

Comment: Print the output

Comment: Check the update

Comment: Thank you again, but I noticed that I can print all the output and I couldn't print for example zeta1 only or zeta2.

Comment: Sorry, what you want to do is unclear

Comment: I want to be able to print zeta1 and zeta2 separately, so If I want to multiply zeta1 with zeta2, I can do that.
As in my code and your code, I can't separate between zeta1 and zeta2